# Assign values based on two tresholds in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a pandas Dataframe named df and it has a column named logvalues.
I want to create a new column, violatedInstances based on these log values.

If Max >= logvalue >= Min assign 0 (Not violated)
If logvalue > Max or logvalue < Min assign 1 (Violated)

```
#create DataFrame
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'logvalue': ['20', '20.5', '18.5', '2', '10'],
                     'ID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']})


Max = 20
min = 15
```

Output should look like below.

| logvalue | ID | violatedInstances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 1 | 0 |
| 20.5 | 2 | 1 |
| 18.5 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 | 1 |

Sorry for asking this simple question. I tried several methods but nothing worked.
How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would convert logvalue to a float so you can perform comparisons

`df_x['logvalue'] = df_x['logvalue'].astype('float')`

Then you can use numpy as such:

```
import numpy as np
df_x['violatedInstances'] = np.where(((df_x['logvalue'] > Max) | (df_x['logvalue'] < Min)), 1, 0)
```

which outputs:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `logvalue` type is `string` so you'll have to convert to float:

```
df_x['violatedInstances'] = df_x['logvalue'].astype(float).apply(lambda x: 1 if (x > Max or x < Min) else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cond1 = pd.to_numeric(df_x['logvalue']).gt(20)
cond2 = pd.to_numeric(df_x['logvalue']).lt(15)
df_x.assign(violatedInstances= (cond1 | cond2).astype('int'))
```

result:

```
logvalue    ID  violatedInstances
0   20      1   0
1   20.5    2   1
2   18.5    3   0
3   2       4   1
4   10      5   1
```